# background image overflow not working

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

I'm having a little trouble getting this image to be displayed correctly.

I have my site setup with a width of 940px and I want to keep this width but have a div within this that is wider and overflows so that you can still see this on larger displays.

```
<div id="cinema-wrapper">
<div id="cinema-displays"></div>
</div>


#cinema-wrapper {
width:940px; 
height:764px;
}
#cinema-displays {
background-image: url(../mackbyte_files/img/cinema-bg.png);
height: 764px;
width: 3109px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-1554.5px;
overflow:visible !important;
}
```

This works (kinda) but I'm left with two problems.

1. It doesn't work in safari (chrome/firefox are fine)
2. It leaves a scroll option only to the right. (e.g. I can scroll further to the right to see the overflowed image).

For 2, I only want the user to see the amount of image depending on their screen resolution.

PS. I know 3109px is huge for web and screen res but im working on a fix before I continue with the image to make it smaller; however, when I do I will still have this issue.

Comment: Please give us a live example.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a block that is 3109px wide into a hole that is 940px wide?

Answer (score 0):

what controls if the inner div is visible or not outside the cinema-wrapper is the overflow of the parent, that you are not setting. so, you should do

```
#cinema-wrapper {
    width:940px; 
    height:764px;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced that kind of problem so here's my approach.

for the HTML:

```
<div id="cinema-wrapper">
    <div id="cinema-subwrapper">
        <div id="cinema-displays"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for the CSS:

```
#cinema-wrapper {
    width: 940px; 
    height: 764px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}

#cinema-subwrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
}

#cinema-displays {
    background: url(../mackbyte_files/img/cinema-bg.png) center top no-repeat;
    height: 764px;
    width: 3109px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)